# How do I "ant release" on project folder

Tags: java, android, eclipse, apache, ant

My issue here is how do I use `ant release` on my project?
I've installed Apache Ant, I first set my cmd to the path of my apache-ant bin folder, `c:\downloads\apache-ant\bin`

Then I set those below.

```
set ANT_HOME=c:\downloads\apache-ant

set JAVA_HOME=c:\programs\java\jdk-1.5.0.05

set PATH=%PATH%;%ANT_HOME%\bin
```

I tried typing `ant` in the cmd and it tells me build failure (which is suppose so).

How do I use `ant release` on my project folder in `c:\eclipseworkspace\test`?
I tried changing path to my project path and use the `ant release` command but they gave a ant not recognized internally and externally message.

I'm just 1 step away from testing the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this and let me know....

```
set ANT_HOME=c:\downloads\apache-ant

set JAVA_HOME=c:\programs\java\jdk-1.5.0.05

set PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin

set PATH=%PATH%;%ANT_HOME%\bin
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi NGoyal, thanks for your help!
What i did was to go into my project folder and do what you told me and it worked.